# Service Worker: files are updated on the server but old version showing in browser

Tags: service-worker, application-cache

I am building a static app with PouchDB on Google AppEngine.

**When I open the site in a browser window, it is showing a version I uploaded several hours ago.**

**If I open the site in an incognito window, the updated version is displayed (therefore I don't think it is actually an error in the console).**

I put a new version number in `app.yaml`

I have migrated all traffic to the new version.

I have cleared my cache, deleted cookies, checked my application data, everything. I even reinstalled Chrome and Firefox.

I updated my Python version and my Google AppEngine Launcher yesterday; the problem pre-dated that update.

Also: just discovered that if I go to the URL of the updated version 
`http://4.[app-id].appspot.com`, it displays the correct, updated version.

This is happening in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge.

Edit: probably should have mentioned that my site uses Service Workers and IndexedDB. I assume my service workers are caching the previous version, but I would have thought that `Ctrl + F5` would clear the cache and show the new version.

Comment: @dan-cornilescu thanks for suggesting the cache issue - it was a caching issue, but the application cache rather than the browser cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it must be the Service Workers caching the pages (which is, after all, what they are supposed to do). This is actually really annoying when you are developing though.

A guy called [Rich Harris has documented this behaviour and some workarounds on a Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/Rich-Harris/fd6c3c73e6e707e312d7c5d7d0f3b2f9).

> **Reloading the page doesn't behave as you'd expect**
>
> If you make a change to your service worker, then reloading the page
>   won't kill the old one and activate the new one (it detects the change
>   by requesting the service worker file each time and comparing the old
>   and the new byte-for-byte), leaving you somewhat confused as to why
>   your changes haven't taken effect. This is because the old window is
>   never actually closed, meaning there's never a time to swap them out –
>   you need to kill the tab completely then reopen it.
>
> Or you can have the browser do that for you by going to the
>   Application tab in devtools (in Canary, not stable Chrome yet), going
>   to the Service Workers section, and checking 'Update on reload'.

**UPDATE** (13 Nov 2017): This functionality is now available in Chrome, so you don't even need to download Canary.

And here's which bits of the application cache to clear:

[image: clearing the application cache]

Comment: If you clear the cache manually, saddly you don't test if the cache will be updated correctly for your users. Unless I'm missing a detail about this chrome feature.