# Google API login not showing in phone browser

Tags: android, iphone, cross-domain, google-authentication

I am building a progressive web app on Google App Engine.

Authentication is via Google API.

It is all working fine on a desktop browser, but when I access the app on a mobile phone browser (both iPhone and Android), the authentication button is hidden.

(I don't think this is because [I am using service workers and it has cached an older version of the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46850418/service-worker-files-are-updated-on-the-server-but-old-version-showing-in-brows), because I have just accessed it on a fresh phone and it is still doing it.)

Could this be a cross-origin or cross-domain conflict?

Comment: Also worth noting that service workers still don't work with iOS.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29895387/service-workers-and-ios-safari

Comment: although they have now said they will support them in the future https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/08/04/service_workers_land_in_webkit_heralding_apple_acceptance/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer, and it now works.

The answer was to [enable CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) with static hosted content on Google Appengine](https://github.com/BauweBijl/gaecors)

(link found on the [Enable CORS website](https://enable-cors.org/index.html))